# Untar as a build step in bazel.

Tags: bazel

I am trying to create a rule (maybe one already exists?), to un-tar a file during a bazel build step.

If I understand correctly all output files need to be known during the "Analysis Phase". To work around this I have a file lets call it manifest.txt which lists all the files in the tar file. However, I don't quite understand how I can read this file as a list outputs for my skylark rule? Is there an easy way to read a file and have each line be a generated output?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, is that manifest file generated beforehand or during the build itself?

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if the manifest file is a source file, i.e. it is NOT generated by some rule in the build.

Rules must declare all their outputs without relying on the content of generated files, therefore it's not supported to create for example a genrule whose `outs` is computed based on a manifest file that's generated by another rule.

To work with a tar file input, the rule needs to unpack the tar with an action, and ultimately produce a predictable amount of outputs (i.e. independent of how many files are there in the tar). Typically this is done by repacking the outputs, that is, the rule would consume one tar and produce another.

Comment: What good would the output tar do? I'd just like to use the decompressed contents (some directory) at runtime, without ever using in the build.